# Countifs Formula with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know there are many similar topics here asked similar question but could not find actually what am I looking for.

Now I have a data array like this;

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllPG.png)

Column A and B are entry/exit hours to the company respectively and they are formatted as "time".

Column C is also formatted as "time" and calculated using this formula:

```
IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,IF(B1<A1,B1-A1,0))
```

to calculate how many hours a person worked using the entry and exit hours in the array.

Column D is formatted as General and includes the company name of person working, which I only need.

What I try to do is a table like this;

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY2Uh.png)

Here Column A is the number of hours people work in one day, starting from 5 hours per day.

To calculate the number of persons worked certain amount of hours per day, I had to choose range of hours, for example for 5 hours per day, I said "people who work 4:45 hours to 5:14. So anyone in between this hours should be counted as they worked 5 hours per day. I did the similar approach for other hours.

Now the formula I created for this for column R4 is;

```
COUNTIFS('06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,">="&TIME(4,45,0),'06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,"<="&TIME(5,14,0),'06.08.2017'!$D$1:$D$300,"COMP1")
```

and for T4;

```
 COUNTIFS('06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,">="&TIME(4,45,0),'06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,"<="&TIME(5,14,0),'06.08.2017'!$D$1:$D$300,"COMP2")
```

This I repeat for every time interval and I get a result. And it is very similar. In fact total number of person are correct for COMP2. BUT they are not for COMP1.

I checked almost everything came into my mind but could not find where I make mistake.

**Update:** I tried to catch where the issue is, and narrowed it down to which values it does not calculate. Result is; I found one of the issues, but I could not manage to find the second one.

Here are the new pictures:

[image: Updated Data Range]

and

[image: Updated Result Page]

First issue was, Row 208. In the Row 208 the time is 00:19 and using  the formula I mentioned above in the Column C, the result was something like #####. So I had to add the date 01/01/1990 manually to make formula give me result. The result I get is as you can see 15:52:00, which is correct. But `COUNTIFS` formula I used in the result page does not count this, so I had to write this date manually also to make it count. Hence I got 1 of the missing person. And if you can help me with this problem to solve it automatically rather than changing adding 01/01/1990 first and then writing the time manually, I would appreciate it.

Now there is another person missing from the result table. Since data range is small, I manually categorized each time range with a color and compared them with the result table.

The problem cell is R10, this number should be 4. But it is 3. So I manually checked which one is not counted from the data table, and it is coming from the Row 222. My first thought was it is related with time, so I tried various time within the same range, but it did not change. But when I rewrite the "COMP1" in D222, it worked.

But why? That is my question. I have lots of data range like this I need to process so it is too much time consuming for me to try to catch problem like this every time, so I need to find the root cause. I used a Macro to generate the Column D. There are two group of people in the company one is named "XYZ'" and other one is "XYZ-B" and I wanted to convert them into one company named "COMP1". Here is the macro:

```
Sub ChangeCompanies()
'
' ChangeCompanies Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace what:="XYZ'", replacement:="COMP1", lookat:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace what:="XYZ-B", replacement:="COMP1", lookat:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Why it is working for every other cell but not this one?

Comment: what is wrong with the total number of persons for comp1? Are there too many, too few?

Comment: You showed formula for T4. What is the real formula in R5?

Comment: @LuuklagThere are missing persons it seems. Not much, 8 people. I tried to follow a pattern to see if I can see what special "thing" this 8 person have but failed to do so.

Comment: @EganWolf Yea I fixed the typo, you are right that R5 was in fact T4. Formula for R5 is;      `COUNTIFS('06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,">="&TIME(5,15,0),'06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,"<="&TIME(5,44,0),'06.08.2017'!$D$1:$D$300,"COMP1")`

Comment: Your data sample only shows 7 entries for COMP1, so either update the data sample to include all entries that are used to build the result table, or make a new result table based on the entries in the data sample.

Comment: For first problem, change your formula to calculate time in column C. You have `B1-A1` in both cases. That can help.

Comment: For second problem you should check if there was a whitespace in the cell after "COMP1".

Comment: While replacing "XYZ" there is `'` at the end? Is it intentional? There is no such sign when replacing "XYZ-B".

Comment: @EganWolf I did not understand the solution you provide for the first one, For the second one; THANKS!! There in fact was a white space. How do I remove those white spaces automatically? Can I write a macro for it? And the `'` after the XYZ is intentional and they send the data to me like that, so it is not a mistake. But the problem is white space as you specified.

Comment: 1. You use `IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,IF(B1<A1,B1-A1,0))` and should be `IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,IF(B1<A1,A1-B1,0))`. 2. There is TRIM function in excel and Trim function in VBA, but there is a small difference in working: one of it (a worksheet function IIRC) deletes additional whitespaces between words as well.

Comment: Also, for the second point: You can use "XYZ'*" as a text to replace. `*` is a wildcard for searching methods in Excel/VBA. Should work in your case and will be better than using `Trim`.

Comment: I just realized I can be wrong about formula in column C... :/

Comment: @EganWolf Yea Column C formula you wrote gives wrong time.For the whitespace, you mean I can add `Selection.Replace what:="XYZ'*", replacement:="COMP1"` to the macro and run it, so it will also search for XYZ' with white spaces and replace that.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @EganWolf thanks will try that now

Comment: Formula for column C: `IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,IF(B1<A1,1-A1+B1,0))`. Change format to date and check different calculations to see what was your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit question to put more details (like formula in R5, it's hard to read them in comments (especially not formatted as code)).
2. You use not strict inequality everywhere (like `<=`). I suggest to change it to strict inequality on one side. You may not see it, but there might be seconds in your time.

In R5:

```
COUNTIFS('06.08.2017'!$C$1:$C$300,">"&TIME(5,14,0),'06.08.2‌​017'!$C$1:$C$300,"<=‌​"&TIME(5,44,0),'06.0‌​8.2017'!$D$1:$D$300,‌​"COMP1")
                                   ^          ^
```

Comment: Using strict inequality would be helpfull if there are too many results found, to avoid counting certain entries twice. It however doesn't help when there are too few results found.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes and no. OP uses not strict inequality AND changes the value of criteria. They can miss one minute for every range.

Comment: Ah yes I see. You could miss out everything from 5,44,0 to 5,45,0.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: Updated the question section.